# how to switch elements in an ArrayList

Tags: java, android, arraylist

The following ArrayList populates a ArrayAdapter.

```
List<String> hold_people = new ArrayList<String>();

hold_people.add("Frank");
hold_people.add("Bob");
hold_people.add("Tom");
hold_people.add("Alice");
hold_people.add("Glen");
```

Frank is in the first spot. but the user wants to see Alice first. How do move Alice to the first spot ?

I can not sort it alphabetically because i must maintain a certain order... based on user request.

Comment: do you want to sort your list?

Comment: i do not want to sort it.

Comment: use `set(index, Obj)`

Answer (score 6):

You can use [`Collections.swap`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Collections.html#swap%28java.util.List%3C?%3E,%20int,%20int%29).

```
Collections.swap(hold_people, 0, hold_people.indexOf("Alice"));
```

This will swap the element that is first in the list with `"Alice"`.

Be aware that `hold_people.indexOf("Alice")` can return `-1` if you don't have the String `"Alice"` in your list, so you may check that the list contains it.

```
int index = hold_people.indexOf("Alice");
if(index != -1)
    Collections.swap(hold_people, 0, index);
```

Comment: @user3134565 Working for me: http://ideone.com/y5vVi1. Make sure you are correctly updating the listview when you made the changes in your adapter.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`Collections.swap(List<?> list, int i, int j)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#swap%28java.util.List,%20int,%20int%29)

> Swaps the elements at the specified positions in the specified list.
>   (If the specified positions are equal, invoking this method leaves the
>   list unchanged.)

Use [`Collections.rotate(List<?> list, int distance)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#rotate%28java.util.List,%20int%29)

> Rotates the elements in the specified list by the specified distance.
>   After calling this method, the element at index i will be the element
>   previously at index (i - distance) mod list.size(), for all values of
>   i between 0 and list.size()-1, inclusive. (This method has no effect
>   on the size of the list.)

Answer (score 0):

If for some reason you don't want to use Collections, you can do

```
String temp = hold_people.get(0);
int i = hold_people.indexOf("Alice");
hold_people.set(0,"Alice");
hold_people.set(i, temp);
```

This will change depending on which one you want to swap, but the basic idea is there.